# Google cloud sql: Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet'

Tags: python, mysql, django, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I've set up a default django/django-wiki project. Local tests work fine. Connecting to cloud sql from the local server (with `google.appengine.ext.django.backends.rdbms`) doesn't work, I believe due to some authentication issue. More importantly, I can't connect from the production server.

I've made sure not to deploy my local `MySQLdb` sitting in my virtual environment directory.

I have the following in `app.yaml`:

```
- name: MySQLdb
  version: "latest"
```

My `DATABASE` entry is the following:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'dbname',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': '/cloudsql/appname:sqlinstance',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}
```

It seems to be working, or at least doesn't complain about missing packages or mysql import issues. My problem is the following (obtained from the production logs, but also visible via the django debug output):

```
File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/MySQLdb-1.2.4b4/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 190, in __init__
    super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
OperationalError: (2013, "Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 38")
```

What could be causing this? Does this mean a connection was made to something but there was no reply? Other posts seem to mention this as an issue when connecting from an external source, but this connection is from app engine AFAIK.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, this was much more straight forward than expected. I had assumed the cloud sql, created with my google account would just grant access to my GAE app by default. This has to be set explicitly, from `Developer Console`->`Storage`->`Cloud SQL`->`instance-name`->`Edit`->`AUTHORIZED APP ENGINE APPLICATIONS`. Or when you create the SQL instance, open the advanced options.

I just added the name of my app in the box, hit save and everything worked.

Comment: Anyone know what that location is now? Not seeing "Authorized App Engine Applications" in that location in Second Generation Cloud SQL.

Comment: @Praxiteles by default it's allowed. if you look under access control, you'll see "All apps in this project are authorized by default. To authorize apps in other projects, follow the steps below."
however, i still get the error the OP mentioned

Comment: This worked for me. I had wrongly assumed that having 0.0.0.0/0 (this was only used for testing, and signifies that "any" connection host is allowed, as instructed in the GAE Django tutorial) listed under authorized networks would grant my app permission, but it seems not.

Comment: @sqram I am also still getting the same error despite all apps being allowed access. Did you ever find a solution? I know it's been a long time, however.

Comment: @turtlefranklin i did. and i unfortunately I don't remember the solution, but i remember it being something simple( i think had to do with the connection formatting/arguments ). Hop on the irc freenode #appengine and try asking there. it's a bit of a slow channel but there some people in here who are experts.

Comment: Note - I needed to add the service account to the permissions even though the database was under the same project as the appengine app. Once added the permission it solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25139344/google-app-engine-and-cloud-sql-lost-connection-to-mysql-server-at-reading-ini/25315098#25315098), whenever an instance dies (for a reason or other), it will restart and, while it restarts, it just shoots this error until it's ready to receive requests.

Your best bet is to try and implement an exponential backoff.  How often does this happen?  Every single time or just once in a while?

Comment: This happens every time, that I can tell. I was able to connect using `google.appengine.ext.django.backends.rdbms` to do the intial `manage.py syncdb`, just not from production. I was wondering if there's some authorization I have to set from the cloud sql side.