# Facing (2006, "Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0") in cloud composer

Tags: airflow, scheduler, google-cloud-composer

I am facing this issue:
`(2006, "Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0")`
on cloud composer on composer-1.16.5-airflow-1.10.14 version, it is an intermittent issue. We have tried cleaning our airflow metadata and modified the code (for example, replacing variable.get() with the jinja template) to reduce the load on db, but we are facing this issue on a daily level. We also restarted the scheduler but the issue started occuring again after two days, also the cpu usage and memory usage graph of airflow database on composer monitoring is constant but the sql database is going into unhealthy state in some time.

The whole error message is as :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  File "/opt/python3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2336, in _wrap_pool_connect    return fn()  File "/opt/python3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 364, in connect    return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)  File "/opt/python3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 778, in _checkout    fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)  File "/opt/python3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 495, in checkout    rec = pool._do_get()  File "/opt/python3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 241, in _do_get    return self._create_connection()  File "/opt/python3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 309, in _create_connection    return _ConnectionRecord(self)  File "/opt/python3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 440, in __init__    self.__connect(first_connect_check=True)  File "/opt/python3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 661, in __connect    pool.logger.debug("Error on connect(): %s", e)  File "/opt/python3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 70, in __exit__    with_traceback=exc_tb,  File "/opt/python3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 182, in raise_    raise exception  File "/opt/python3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 656, in __connect    connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)  File "/opt/python3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/strategies.py", line 114, in connect    return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)  File "/opt/python3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 493, in connect    return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)  File "/opt/python3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 85, in Connect    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)  File "/opt/python3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 208, in __init__    super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (2006, "Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0")
```

Comment: It might be happening due to generic `GKE failures` because nodes with `airflow-sqlproxy` are overloaded.
I suggest you try performing an upgrade of the nodes’ machine type, granting more resources by [changing their machine type](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/managing/updating#upgrading_the_machine_type).I would suggest executing that resource upgrade also for the `Cloud SQL` node by going to `Environment Configuration > Resources > Cloud SQL` machine type item, and then click `Edit`, to change its machine type.Let me know if this solves your issue.

Comment: airflow-sqlproxy cpu usage is not high, as if it would be overloaded then the cpu usage and memory should be on peak.

Comment: As you mentioned  `sql DB` going into `unhealthy` did you check whether it had been restarted  or not ? You can find similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25139344/google-app-engine-and-cloud-sql-lost-connection-to-mysql-server-at-reading-ini).If SQL is going into unhealthy frequently then its better to upgrade.
Also the Composer version  you are currently using is already [out of support from May,2022](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/concepts/versioning/composer-versions#images).Your composer will work but it will not receive any product fix or security updates.

Comment: Thanks @SayanBhattacharya, we are planning to upgrade our composer now.

Comment: I have posted an answer with all collected info.

Answer (score 1):

There could be multiple reasons as the error itself is too general, so it makes a lot of different possibilities for what could go wrong. Known causes:

1. Connections are blocked by firewall rules.
2. This can also temporarily happen while an instance is being restarted.
3. Generic GKE failures because nodes with `airflow-sqlproxy` are overloaded.

Since it's an intermittent issue, we can assure connections are not being blocked by firewall rules. We might have to check whether any instances have been restarted. And lastly to avoid generic GKE failures you can upgrade your [machine types](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/managing/updating#upgrading_the_machine_type), allocating more resources.

Also as I already mentioned in the comments you're using an old version of Composer which is  [out of support from May,2022](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/concepts/versioning/composer-versions#images). Its always better to upgrade your composer to a certain version which will have support from Google .